# How change mime type using python?

Tags: python

I have doc file.its meta data shown in below[image]

I want to change it mime type to image/png in python(I am a script kiddie hacker. I want to upload php
file to server by changing mime type )
How change this.i need python solution.

Comment: But why you have tagged c#, java, php & phyton??

Comment: why negative mark? what the problem with my Q?

Comment: The problem is the question and the lack of details? Why do you tag c# and java although it is unrelated to both?

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't normally change that mimetype in that way. The mimetype you are referring to on an upload is submitted by the browser (and determined by the browser).

If you want to upload this in a way where your browser misrepresents the mime type you either install a plugin or you write a script to upload to the form yourself.